# R programming how to index duplicate rows?

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicate rows in object DT below and then give them an index as a way of grouping them.  This code correctly indexes and groups the second set of duplicates by setting DT$newindex to 2 but is, for some reason, missing the first set of dups in object DT. I've used message() to check that i and p are correct and they are. What's wrong here?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(A = rep(1:3, each=4), 
                 B = rep(1:4, each=3), 
                 C = rep(1:2, 6), key = "A,B,C")

dups <- unique(DT[duplicated(DT)])

DT$newindex <- NA
for (p in 1: nrow(dups)) {
     for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) {
     DT$newindex[i] <- ifelse(DT$A[i]==dups$A[p] & DT$B[i] == dups$B[p] & DT$C[i]== dups$C[p],p,0)
    }
  }
```

Comment: just to answer the "what's wrong here?" part: at the second pass of the loop you replace the "1" you put at the first pass with "0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain your index, you can do:

```
DT[, newindex:=sapply(1:nrow(DT), 
                      function(x) {
                          i <- which(sapply(1:nrow(dups), function(y) all(dups[y]==DT[x])))
                          if (length(i)) i else 0})]
DT
#    A B C newindex
# 1: 1 1 1        1
# 2: 1 1 1        1
# 3: 1 1 2        0
# 4: 1 2 2        0
# 5: 2 2 1        0
# 6: 2 2 2        0
# 7: 2 3 1        0
# 8: 2 3 2        0
# 9: 3 3 1        0
#10: 3 4 1        0
#11: 3 4 2        2
#12: 3 4 2        2
```

Answer (score 0):

how about pasting all the columns to produce the index?

```
DT[,ID:=do.call(paste0,.SD)]
```

then show some stats for fun

```
DT[,.N,by=ID]
```